# Error instantiating extensions registry for chart.theme

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a *PDF* with *JasperReports*.

At the first time I try, I get this error:

```
ERROR [net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry] Error instantiating extensions registry for chart.theme 
from vfszip:My-App.ear/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-4.7.0.jar/jasperreports_extension.properties
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: 
Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [defaultChartPropertiesBean.xml]
Offending resource: URL 
[My-App.ear/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-4.7.0.jar/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/chartThemesBeans.xml];
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: 
Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [chartConstantsBean.xml]
Offending resource: URL 
[My-App.ear/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-4.7.0.jar/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/defaultChartPropertiesBean.xml]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL 
[My-App.ear/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-4.7.0.jar/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/chartConstantsBean.xml];
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: 
Class [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler] for namespace 
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/util] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:219)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:148)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory.getBeanFactory(SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory.java:101)
```

However, the *PDF* is generated without any problem.

Plus, the next time I try to generate one *PDF*, no more errors. This only occurs on the first generation.

What is a reason? And how I can avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Problem Solved.

I included jasperreports-chart-themes-4.7.0.jar in my classpath. However, this jar wasn't used anymore. I only used the default themes from jasper.

Deleting this jar from .ear and everything works fine.

Thanks anyway